# List of heterogeneous elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Why doesn't the following code give an error when I am trying to add two elements of different types in one list?

```
List list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add("1");
```

Comment: In some sense, this is not even a `List<Object>`: You are not giving type parameters at all, so it's a *raw type*. That means that all generic type checks will become obsolete. So you should declare it as a `List<Object>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't declare the list to be of specific type, it treats it as a list of objects.

int 1 is auto boxed to Integer and "1" is String and hence both are objects.

Answer (score 3):

In `Java 7` it works. For previous versions you should exactly provide generic type. Because you have 2 different type instances (`Integer` and `String`), the common type for them is `Object` so you need declare as following.

```
List list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
```